# Already uninstalled apache2 in Debian but it's still there?

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, aptitude

I performed the following command `apt-get remove apache2` but when I type `service --status-all` apache2 is still up in the list. How can you completely uninstall apache2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `apt-get remove apache2`, this will still leave config files behind, though.

To fully uninstall apache2 and remove its config files try `apt-get purge apache2`.

Before trying each of these, take a look at `man apt-get` to make sure, that the mentioned commands will do what you want.

Comment: Wow, what a bad typo, I  mean I typed `apt-get remove apache2`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I had to  run the following:

```
apt-get remove apache2-utils
```